# Force make to use python2?

Tags: python, makefile

I'm trying to build an Android kernel with `make` command. The script uses `python2` to log errors in the `print >> sys.stderr, line` fashion. So instead of actual error output I get errors about incorrect python syntax.

I had an idea to delete `python3`, but I read that it could be harmful to the system as it comes bundled and many things might depend on it. Tried adding `alias python=python2` at the end of the `.bashrc` file, rebooted the terminal, tested it with the line:

```
echo `python -c "print 'test'"`  # prints 'test' correctly
```

But when I `make`, I still get the same errors, it somehow manages to use `python3` anyways.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: [Python 2 has been officially dead](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) for over two years now.  You might consider upgrading the code to a recent version of Python 3.

Comment: @MarkRansom I suggest you tell it Xiaomi Android kernel developers, I'm only the end user haha :)

Comment: Since you're the one doing Android builds, I suggest *you* tell them.  It used to be that Python 2 was the "safe" choice because you could assume everybody had it.  I'm afraid increasingly in the future it's going to be the other way around.

Comment: @MarkRansom man, I don't care really which language version is used as long as the kernel compiles. It's only used to print errors anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show your Makefile.  The easiest thing is to define the absolute path of python on your system.  You can get that by using the `which` command.  Then, change `python` in Makefile to the absolute path that you found out using `which python2`.

Comment: I `which`'ed and my path was `/usr/bin/python2`. Just went ahead and replaced every occurrence of `python` with `/usr/bin/python2` in `Makefile` and it helped! Now I can see the errors, finally. Didn't include `Makefile` because it's around 2k lines long :)